# How check if there is an array or an object in jq?

Tags: json, jq

For example, I want to extract the values from a key, but that key sometimes contains an object (I mean just one value) or sometimes contains an array (i mean multiples values). HOw check if there is an array or there is an object? thanks.

Answer (score 36):

Use the `type` function:

> `type`
>   The type function returns the type of its argument as a string,
>   which is one of null, boolean, number, string, array or object.

Example 1:

```
echo '[0, false, [], {}, null, "hello"]' | jq 'map(type)'
[
  "number",
  "boolean",
  "array",
  "object",
  "null",
  "string"
]
```

Example 2:

```
echo '[0,1]' | jq 'if type=="array" then "yes" else "no" end'
"yes"
```

Example 3:

```
echo '{"0":0,"1":1}' | jq 'if type=="array" then "yes" else "no" end'
"no"
```

Comment: Hi @Hans, can you please provide the example for array of elements also .
[{"foo": null , "bar": "less interesting data"},{"foo": "null" , "bar": "less interesting data"}, {"foo": ["a","b"] , "bar": "less interesting data"}].

To check whether the foo is array or string.

Am using below jq commond in jqPlay
.[]|{"result" : if .foo  == null then [ ]  end }

Answer (score 15):

I have fields that are sometimes strings sometimes arrays and I want to iterate over them.   This handles this case:

```
... | if type=="string" then [.] else . end | .[] | ...
```

Comment: this was the solution for exactly the same situation for me, except that it was sometimes object sometimes array and `| if type!="array" then [.] else . end |` is more generic